# PHP require Permission Denied even with 777 permissions and correct group on file + directory

Tags: php, apache, permissions, filesystems

I've never had a problem with PHP being able to read files when group and user are set correctly.

Apache is running under the www-data user so I set everything (group and user permissions) to www-data with 777 chmod and still nothing is working.

No idea what's going on.

PHP is not in safe mode.

code:

```
require ('/root/app/class/api.php');
```

filesystem:

```
$ pwd
/root/app/class
$ ls -la
total 76
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data  4096 Oct  8 10:59 .
drwxrwxrwx 9 www-data www-data  4096 Sep 25 21:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     26896 Jan 13  2014 something_else.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     root     32807 Mar 11  2015 something.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data  3439 Mar  3  2015 api.php
```

error:

```
Warning: require(/root/app/class/api.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/website.com/htdocs/app_frontend/include/config.php on line 36

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/root/app/class/api.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/website.com/htdocs/app_frontend/include/config.php on line 36
```

tried debugging:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

$file = '/root/app/class/api.php';

echo sprintf ( '%o', fileperms ( $file ) ), PHP_EOL;
echo posix_getpwuid ( fileowner ( $file ) ), PHP_EOL; // Get Owner
echo posix_getpwuid ( posix_getuid () ), PHP_EOL; // Get User

if (is_file ( $file )) {
    echo "is_file", PHP_EOL;
    ;
}

if (is_readable ( $file )) {
    echo "is_readable", PHP_EOL;
    ;
}

if (is_writable ( $file )) {
    echo "is_readable", PHP_EOL;
}

fopen ( $file, "w" );
```

result:

```
Warning: fileperms(): stat failed for /root/app/class/api.php in /var/www/website.com/...

Warning: fileowner(): stat failed for /root/app/class/api.php in /var/www/website.com/...
```

edit: there is no SElinux enabled on my server, here is an output of apachectl DUMP_MODULES

```
$ /usr/sbin/apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *entire* path to that file needs to be readable in order for PHP to open it.

For example:

```
# cd /
# ls -al
drwx------ 3 root  wheel  102 jan  1  2014 root
# sudo su
Password:
$ cd /root
$ mkdir pub
$ chmod 777 pub
$ vi pub/test.php

<?php
echo "Hi, world!";
:wq

$ chmod 666 pub/test.php
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > include "/root/pub/test.php";
Hi, world!
php > exit
$ exit
# php -a
Interactive shell

php > include "/root/pub/test.php";
PHP Warning:  include(/root/pub/test.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in php shell code on line 1
...
```

Note that, in this example, `/root` is *and should always be* readable, writable and executable *only by root*.

**TL;DR:**
Move your files out of `/root`.  Make sure the *entire* path to your file is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Disable SELinux and see the result. If that was the case, simply install and run a program named SELinux troubleshooter.

1. Find the related alert.
2. Click on troubleshoot
3. Check any listed plugin and execute the suggested command in terminal.